# Quick documentation in Intellij IDEA is painfully slow

Tags: performance, intellij-idea

I am using IDEA 13.x and the quick documentation is painfully slow. I think the reason is that this documentation is fetched over the internet.

Eclipse fetches this documentation directly from the JDKs src.zip (or other source files). There is NO fetching delay.

Can I somehow configure IDEA to get the documentation it shows in the popup from the local src files?

Comment: Have a look at project settings->libraries and see if you libraries have an entry for the JavaDocs

Comment: Yes. Some JavaFX docu URL was automatically added by IDEA it seems. It's under Project Settings > SDKs > Documentation Paths tab

Comment: Hmm great.. with the latest update this has become slow for me, but there aren't any URLs listed under documentation paths. :/

Answer (score 11):

I met the same problem you mentioned. I guess it's because IDEA is trying to fetch doc online with the url specified in *Project Structure > SDKs > Documentation Paths*, so I deleted the url(back it up first), and it's much faster now.

Comment: Life saver! The only url was to JavaFX still it made a huge difference.